# Stop a service after time

Tags: android, service, timer

I want to stop my Service after a user defined time (choosen in a activity). 
Now I want to start the timer in the service, but I cant use static timer because I have to stop the service (stopService(), stopSelf() are non-static methods.

Is there a simple way to do it?

(Now I used a handler with a runnable which checks if a variable is set to true and then starts the timer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AlarmManager`. Call `set()` on an `AlarmManager`, supplying the time when you want your service to stop and a `getService()` `PendingIntent` that will send a command to your service. In `onStartCommand()`, when you receive the `Intent` command from the `PendingIntent`, call `stopSelf()`.